# Know thread Id of procedure

Tags: mysql

Doing

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE STATE = "executing";
```

It contains a column `Id` which is the Id number of all the threads currently running. Now in my `MySQL` procedure, at the beginning I wish to know the ID of the thread executing it. What query will return the ID of the thread running the procedure?

Secondly: I wish to know it because, the queries in my application are quite long running. I want to automate the process that as soon I get a fresh request, my application will cancel the already running query by `Kill query someID`. For this I need to know the `ID` of already running procedure. Does `Kill query` command affect the stability? As per [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html), it looks safe as it only sets a flag and connection is intact.

Comment: you can do `show [full] processlist()` to get the same results.

Comment: @DevZer0 it returns complete list. I just want the Id of thread currently procedure (itself)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the CONNECTION_ID() function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id